# imageview not updating after an image is picked

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3

I have the following problem. I use a imagepickerdelegate to choose a image from my photo library and to apply this in the UIImageView. The problem is that it won't update the UIImageview with my chosen image.

I inherit both

> UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

This is my image view.

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 99  / 2
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profileimg")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    return imageView

}()
```

Then the functions to handle choosing and setting the image inside the UIImageView look like these.

```
func addProfilePhoto() {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedPickedImage
    } else if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = pickedImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        print("set image")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My log gives the following messages when I tap on the UIImageView:

> [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

And when I choose an image it confirms that there is an image but it won't show.

> set image

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, seem you have not code for display profileImageView on screen. So, you do not see it. Example:

```
profileImageView.frame = ........
self.view.addSubview(profileImageView)
```

Comment: Oh sorry I left that part out since it had a lot of constraint stuff as well, but I do include it. I even see the imageview and I can click on it to get my uiimagepickercontroller to show up. I can go trough the whole proces of picking and image and it even returns the image in code but it just won't show.

Comment: Maybe, problem is here: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {}
 Let try remove it.

Comment: I have tried that, It wouldn't solve the problem. I inserted it to be sure that the image change happens on the main queue